# How to take parameters from a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, passwords

I am creating a password reset component where a user will enter their email address and if the email exists a reset email gets sent to this user.  The reset email contains a URL like `website.reset/{userId}/{token}`.

I don't want to send the userID or token from the backend to the front in order to avoid phishing.  What I need is for the user to click the link and be routed to a valid URL.  I want to extract the userID and token from the URL and insert them into my Routes page

I want my Route to read the information from the URL and render as a valid page:

```
<Router primary={false}>
   <UpdatePassword path="/password-confirm/:uid/:token"  />
</Router>
```

I am thinking I need to add a lifecycle function to my `UpdatePassword` component where I `GET` parameters from the URL when a user lands on website.password-confirm/1234/abc. I haven't been able to get this to work however.

Is it possible for my app to read the information in the URL or will it need to be given that info beforehand?

Comment: what is the routing structure in your app? Do you provide ssr? is this a create-react-app project ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<Route path="...." component={UpdatePassword} />` ?

Comment: @Afsanefda Yes I am using create-react-app.  There is no SSR. I am using Reach-Router.  I'm not using any nested routes.  I am allowing all URLs beginning with `/password-confirm/` to render so when a user goes to `/password-confirm/1234/abc` they will arrive on the same page as just `/password-confirm/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use above line of code to get params value.

```
const { uid, token } = this.props.match.params
```

Comment: I have tried a few variations of this however I always get an error message telling me something is not defined.  I am using React Hooks so that may make a difference.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet where and how you are trying?

Comment: I have tried two different ways.  First I tried adding this line after my  component declaration `const UpdatePassword = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [passType, setPassType] = useState('password')
  //const {uid, token} = this.props.match.params;`

Comment: Then I tried writing a function to run on a button click. `const testuseEffect= () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/reset-password-confirm/', {
      params: {
        resetPasswordToken: this.props.match.params
      }
    })}`

Comment: The error I get says cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

Comment: When using React Hooks, there is no class, so `this` doesn't reference what you think it does. You can just use `props.match.params` as `props` is just a function argument with a hook.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk . I have tried this and I receive an error saying 'cannot read property params of undefined'.

Comment: If you try `console.log(props)` in that useEffect, what do you see as the output? What props are there?

Comment: you are using Reach-Router so inside props you will get directly params value

Comment: `props.paramsName` something like that.

Do follow this link to  check examples with Reach-Router
https://github.com/reach/router/blob/master/examples/crud/src/App.js

Comment: Perfect.  'props.id' is where I needed to look. Thank you.